# Why does $\frac {100 - 100}{100 - 100}$ give 3 answers?

Tags: proof-verification

I recently saw a Maths Problem, to which I got 3 different answers, all of which seem correct.

## Case 1

$\frac {100 - 100}{100 - 100} = \frac{0}{0} = \infty$

## Case 2

$\frac{100-100}{100-100} = \frac{(100-100)\div(100-100)}{(100-100)\div(100-100)} = \frac{1}{1}= 1$

## Case 3

$\frac{100-100}{100-100} = \frac{10^2 -10^2}{10(10-10)}=\frac{(10+10)(10-10)}{10(10-10)}=\frac{\frac{(10+10)(10-10)}{(10-10)}}{\frac{10(10-10)}{(10-10)}} = \frac{10+10}{10} = \frac{20}{10} = 2$

Now, I know that in mathematics,there is *exactly* 1 solution to every problem. But then, how can this be?

Comment: The value does not exist, since you are dividing by $0$. So if you assume that it exists, you are assuming a contradiction, and you can prove any number of nonsensical things.

Comment: "All of which seem correct". Is dividing by zero correct? Is infinity an element of the real numbers?

Comment: Thou shalt not divide by zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both in cases $2$ and $3$, you are dividing by $$100-100=0$$ which is an invalid operation.

In case you are just freaking out, "*Where?*", I will show it to you.

> Case $2$ - Step $2$ and in Case $3$ - Step $4$

Comment: Your explanation is correct.

Comment: By the way, +1 to your comment.. @MithileshUpadhyay

Comment: So, this means that dividing by anything that solves to 0 is wrong?

Comment: No, I said DIVIDED **BY** 0

Comment: Yes, see [here](https://brilliant.org/wiki/division-by-zero/).

Comment: Thanks a lot for that Link! You should include it in the answer!

Answer (score 0):

It's conventional not to permit division by $0$ but if you set $0=\infty$ then this makes $0$ an absorbing element under both addition and multiplication and that also makes it absorbing under division.  Then every version of your equation has a valid solution and the solution by any method gives $\frac {100 - 100}{100 - 100}=0=\infty$.

So you have:

$0a=0=\infty\forall a$

$a\div0=\infty=0\forall a$

and

$a\times0=0=\infty\forall a$

But this has the downside of denying you:

$a+0=a\forall a$ because instead you have $0+a=0=\infty$

so you can do what you're trying to do (divide by zero) but basically it's the equivalent of removing what you conventionally think of as $0$ (the identity under addition) from your algebra and replacing it with $\infty$ (the absorbing element under addition) so it really messes up much of what you take for granted.

Answer (score 0):

I would say, that you cannot divide by zero and therefore the result is undefined.

Actually you divide in all 3 cases by zero.

Step in Case 1:

$\frac{0}{0} = \infty$, where it should be $\frac{0}{0} = undefined$

Step in Case 2:

$\frac{(100-100)÷(100-100)}{(100-100)÷(100-100)} = 1$, where you divide by a term which itself is $undefined$ based on the reason explained above.

Step in Case 3:

$\frac{(10+10)(10-10)}{10(10-10)} = \frac{\frac{(10+10)(10-10)}{(10-10)}}{\frac{10(10-10)}{(10-10)}}$, where you divide numerator and denominator by (10-10) which is zero.

In a practical application, I would prefer to throw an exception with the specifically most convenient reaction.